# Variance of a list of numbers in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

For some reason, my code below isn't giving me the right solution to solve the sample variance of x= [7, 6, 8, 4, 2, 7, 6, 7, 6, 5].  The solution should be 3.067, but I keep getting 11.044 and I have no idea why.  Can someone help?

```
def var_method_0(x):
    n = len(x) # Number of samples
    mean=sum(x)/n
    variance=sum([((mean-i)**2) for i in range(n)])/(n-1)
    return variance
```

Comment: is this python 2 or 3?

Comment: this is python 3

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
def var_method(lst):
    n = len(lst)
    mean = sum(lst) / float(n)
    return sum((mean - x) ** 2 for x in lst) / float(n - 1)
```

I fixed two things:

- Making sure that the divisions are returning float values (not a problem in Python 3.x, but could mess things in Python 2.x)
- In the line where you calculate the actual variance, you don't want to iterate over the `range`, but over the actual values of the list of numbers

Apart from that I did a bit of cleaning-up and renaming, to make the code more concise. Now it works as expected:

```
var_method([7, 6, 8, 4, 2, 7, 6, 7, 6, 5])
=> 3.066666666666667
```